# do I need eval?

Tags: javascript, function, eval

I've searched the web for what eval does and here is what I have found:

> The eval() method evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

And I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea), which says that it is **evil**.
But I really don't understand what does it do, i.e I don't see when to use eval.
I mean:

```
var x= 3;
var y =5;
var z = eval("x+y");
// is the same as:
var z = x+y;
```

so as I see it's just adding characters to my code. Can somebody give me an example of why eval was created in the first place?

Comment: 99.999% of the time, `eval` is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @RocketHazmat so why was it created?

Comment: @user689: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089532/why-does-eval-exist :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows execute dynamicly generated code, not just "x+y".

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: I think it is not bad example for using it http://jsfiddle.net/ondras/hYfN3/

Comment: It possible to avoid use it but sometimes using it is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Eval allows you to evaluate a string as javascript code. This means you can do things like evaluate a string to call a function:

```
function add(x,y){
     return (x+y);
}

stringToEval = 'add(5,6)';

eval(stringToEval);
```

This code would run the function by evaluating the string as a function call.
So I would say you do not need to use eval here. Just add the two variables.