# Node.js async await in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I'm building an endpoint /users which will return the contents in the Users.json file. I'm using aysnc/await feature.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var readFile = Promise.promisify(fs.readFile);
const util = require('util');

app.get('/users', async (req, res, next) => {
try {
const user = await readFile('./users.json');
return eval(user);
//res.send(JSON.parse(data));
// res.json(user);
} catch (e) {
//this will eventually be handled by your error handling middleware
next(e) 
}
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("listening on port 3000");
});
```

This throws the below error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
>
> at createScript (vm.js:56:10) at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:542:28) at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:579:10) at Module.load (module.js:487:32) at tryModuleLoad
>   (module.js:446:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3) at
>   Module.runMain (module.js:604:10) at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7) at
>   startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)

I'm using the  npm 3.10.10 with node v6.11.3.

Can someone please guide where I have gone wrong?

Comment: [**Never ever** use `eval` to parse JSON!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4270597/1048572) In node.js, `JSON.parse` is always available.

Comment: What is `Promise.promisify`? Did you mean `util.promisify`?

Comment: I don't get any error using the code you posted.

Comment: Yup..  I meant util.promisify(), however I guess that's not causing this issue. @Bergi Was there any code change done apart from the util.promisify? I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Looks like node v6.11.3 does not support `async`/`await` syntax. Update it.

Comment: asyn-await feature available from node version 8+ only. If you cannot change the version, try using generator functions with Co.

Answer (score 3):

[Async/await is only available in Node versions 8 an up](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions). Try using a newer Node version if possible.

Comment: should be version 8. Nodejs 7.5 supports async await only with the harmony flag

Comment: Thanks.. It did work after ugrading the node version to v10.13.0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling:

`return eval(user);`

You should call:

`res.send(JSON.parse(user));`

or

`res.send(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(user)));`

and use bodyParser.json() middleware if returning an object.

Likewise in the catch block,

`res.status(500).send(‘there was an error’);`

and log the error to your console.

——-

Also, fs.readFile takes another param, the encoding.  Use ‘utf-8’.  It returns a buffer, not a string, if you leave it out.